# Retriving output from two entry dialog box with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

I have the following code to generate a two entry input dialog box and a button to close the "app".

However I cannot cannot get the values out of the outputs. They always come out as x and N. The code was not developed by me since I am a beginner with python. Can anyone give me hand with this?

```
 from tkinter import Tk, Text, TOP, BOTH, X, N, LEFT, RIGH      
 from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Label, Entry, Button

        class SimpleDialog(Frame):

        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()

            self.output1 = ""
            self.output2 = ""
            self.initUI()

        def initUI(self):

            self.master.title("Simple Dialog")
            self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

            frame1 = Frame(self)
            frame1.pack()

            lbl1 = Label(frame1, text="Input1", width=6)
            lbl1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=10)

            self.entry1 = Entry(frame1)
            self.entry1.pack(padx=5, expand=True)

            frame2 = Frame(self)

            frame2.pack()

            lbl2 = Label(frame2, text="Input2", width=6)
            lbl2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=10)

            self.entry2 = Entry(frame2)
            self.entry2.pack(padx=5, expand=True)

            frame3 = Frame(self)
            frame3.pack()


            btn = Button(frame3, text="Submit", command=self.onSubmit)
            btn.pack(padx=5, pady=10)

        def onSubmit(self):

            self.output1 = self.entry1.get()
            self.output2 = self.entry2.get()
            self.quit()

    def main():

        # This part triggers the dialog
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
        app = SimpleDialog()
        root.mainloop()

        user_input = (app.output1, app.output2)

        try:
            root.destroy()
        except:
            pass
        return user_input

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

kind regards!

Comment: _"I cannot cannot get the values out of the outputs"_ - why can't you? What happens when you try?

Comment: *"cannot cannot get the values out"*: Your code works as expected. [Edit] your Question and explain in detail: **What** do you want to do with the `values`? As it stands, you only `.quit()`. **Step 1**: Add a own `Button(..., command=.self.quit)` to close the `app`.

Comment: I want the string that is placed on entry 1 and entry 2

Comment: Currently the two input windows appear. I would like to put some string as input and get it when submit is pressed. Pressing submit would also close the window.

Comment: @ManuelOliveira Why do you use the PyQt tag?

Comment: What bit of code am I missing? I would like to retrieve the input on entry1 and entry 2 but the outlput is always X,N